# find largest item in list that exceeds a constant value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given a list of prices, I want to find the *index* of the the largest price that exceeds a certain minimum. My current solution looks like this:

```
public class Price {
    public static Integer maxPriceIndex(List<Integer> prices, Integer minPrice) {

        OptionalInt maxPriceIndexResult = IntStream.range(0, prices.size())
                .reduce((a, b) -> prices.get(a) > prices.get(b) ? a : b);

        if (maxPriceIndexResult.isPresent()) {
            int maxPriceIndex = maxPriceIndexResult.getAsInt();
            int maxFuturePrice = prices.get(maxPriceIndex);

            if (maxFuturePrice > minPrice) {
                return maxPriceIndex;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> prices = Arrays.asList(5, 3, 2);
        Integer result = maxPriceIndex(prices, 6);
        System.out.println("Final result: " + result);
    }
}
```

I don't like this mix of imperative and functional code, but can't figure out a way of changing the reducer so that it also compares the price with `minPrice`. Is there a purely functional solution to this problem?

Comment: Don't try to put a comparison into the reducer.  Instead, *filter* the index stream before reduction to eliminate those that do not satisfy the min price criterion.

Comment: And also - what should happen when there are several same max prices? Index of first one should be returned?

Comment: @michalk yeah, I think so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the filter before finding the max.

```
IntStream.range(0, prices.size())
            .filter(i -> prices.get(i) > minPrice)
            .reduce((a, b) -> prices.get(a) > prices.get(b) ? a : b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `filter`ing the stream as you process, you can perform a `max` based on the custom comparator instead of `reduce` as:

```
return IntStream.range(0, prices.size())
                .filter(i -> prices.get(i) > minPrice)
                .boxed()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(prices::get))
                .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from all the answers you got, it's easy to make poorly performing implementations by accident.  Not one of the other answers is as fast as the code you originally wrote.  (@MikeFHay's is pretty good, though)

Maybe just do:

```
int index = IntStream.range(0, prices.size())
        .reduce((a, b) -> prices.get(a) > prices.get(b) ? a : b)
        .orElse(-1);

return (index >= 0 && prices.get(index) > minPrice) ? index : null;
```

Optionals and Streams are handy to have around, but their use is not mandatory, and you don't have to jump through hoops to use them.

What you really want here is an `OptionalInt.filter` or `OptionalInt.boxed`, but Java doesn't provide them.

Comment: Good answer while I don't like magic number in internal processing (`-1` to convey not found) .It is a pity that the `OptionalInt` API be so poor in terms of transformation.

Answer (score 0):

First filter all values greater than `minPrice` and then sort them in `reverseOrder`, next get the index of first max element using `findFirst` value or if list is empty return `null`

```
return list.stream()
           .filter(i->i>minPrice)
           .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
           .findFirst()
           .map(v->list.indexOf(v))
           .orElse(null);
```

If you want to get the last index of max element you can use `lastIndexOf` method

```
.map(v->list.lastIndexOf(v))
```

Comment: I guess it should work now, but what should happen when there are several same max prices? :D

Comment: That's a good question to OP @michalk and also my code returns the index of first max element

Comment: yes I understand. I think this solution is sufficient for what OP requested and the downvoter should retract the downvote now.

Comment: the `indexOf` is too slow

Comment: may be better than doing 100's of `get(index)` ? @MattTimmermans

Comment: The `indexOf`  will be called only once as it is preceeded by `findFirst` - so it is basically the same as filtering (O(n)) and then reducing.

Comment: ah, right.  That's not so bad.  The sort is sort is also slow, though.

Comment: Right, sorting might be slow.